# How can I extract a substring from a flowfile data in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a file that has data in txt format and each line in the file is 1 record.
I am using splittext processor to split the flowfile in 1 record/file.

I want to extract a substring from the record.I need to get a substring from start to nth index.

```
e.g.
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345678910'

result flowfile for first 10 chars= abcdefghij
```

[image: flow]

[image: ExtractText] - I am using default settings in this except I tried adding an attribute (att1) as mentioned in some of the online forums. It's not helping.

Please help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using expression langauge to get a substring in your ExtractText, which is incorrect.

The Dynamic Properties of ExtractText populate an attribute based on a RegEx pattern.

So you could use the pattern `(.*)` to extract the entire text into your attribute named `att1`. You could then use the UpdateAttribute processor to update that attribute with the same Expression Language statement you are using `${att1:substring(0,60)}` - but using the name of the new attribute you have created.

See the documentation for ExtractText and look at the Dynamic Properties section
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/index.html

Comment: Hi @Sdairs, thanks. I tried this but I am still  getting the same content (the whole string). I used ExtractText and added ```input=(.*)```. And in UpdateAttribute I added ```att1=${input:substring(0,60)}```. Do I need to add any other param or something?

Comment: @Sdairsn, nvm I figured it out. Thanks.