# How can we use UpdateAttribute processor for assigning variable of FlowFile content in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, update-attributes

I need some help in UpdateAttribute processor:
I have a CSV file which contains hostnames. I need to separate each hostname in the FlowFile and pass it as a variable to the REST API.
My REST API part is working fine when passing data manually. However, I didn't get how to pass a variable value as hostname in it.

Sharing sample file:

```
SRHAPP001,SRHWEBAPP002,SRHDB006,SRHUATAPP4,ARHUATDB98
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71140748/how-to-create-a-loop-for-dynamic-dates-apache-nifi/71144254#71144254

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your goal, but I assume that you try to pass the hostname to your REST API module by using FlowFile variables.

You can achieve this by using the `ExtractText`-Processor. You simply use RegEx for separating your hostnames from the CSV file.

For more information, see
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/

[How can I extract a substring from a flowfile data in Nifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64886018/how-can-i-extract-a-substring-from-a-flowfile-data-in-nifi)

If needed, you can split incoming FlowFiles on every hostname by using `SplitContent`-Processor

Comment: Yeah, SplitContent works, for passing a hostname as variable, i have added one more processor ExtractText, and add the attribute into it.